# imacro to auto fill a form

Tags: imacros

I am using the concept of imacro to auto fill a form. I have recorded one and got the script.

For eg:-

```
VERSION BUILD=7601105 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://mysite/home.aspx
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:home.aspx ATTR=ID:ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsername CONTENT=samual
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ACTION:home.aspx ATTR=ID:ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword CONTENT=sampassword
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:ContentPlaceHolder1_btnLogin
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:ContentPlaceHolder1_bpo_TabContainer_tbpnl_lnk_address_0
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:IMAGE FORM=ID:form1 ATTR=ID:Logout
```

But my actual requirement is on a button click I need to call this macro and each time the form field value may changes. So I need to dynamically pass these new values to the macros.  I am thinking like clicking on that button I will pass new value to these script and save this macro and call that macro. But I am not sure is this the way it will work or is it possible to call a macro (like above) from a program that is created using imacro?

Thanks

---

Thanks a lot for the answer . It gave some insight. But can you explain a bit more. Because I am completely new to the imacro concept.

```
    <html>
 <body> 
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function runimacros() {
      var iim1 = new ActiveXObject("imacros");
      var ret
      ret = iim1.iimInit("-fx");
      ret = iim1.iimDisplay("Test Macro");
      ret = iim1.iimPlay ("testmacro.iim");//this is the macro which I created in firefox and located C:\Users\MyName\Documents\iMacros\Macros\testmacro.iim
      ret = iim1.iimExit();
   }
   </script>
 <a href="javascript:runimacros()">Click to run iMacros</font></a>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Please note that the macro which created(testmacro.iim) is using firefox and it is located in the above location.

I tried the approach 'http://wiki.imacros.net/JavaScript' but is not working. Am I missing something? I tried the above code in Visual studio and made the default browser as IE. Please give any suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call an Imacros program (.iim) from another one, but you can use javascript to call one or more iim files passing one variable:

```
var ret;    
ret = iimDisplay ("optional message to be displayed on the Imacros banner");
var i='input variable'
ret = iimSet("i", i);
ret = iimPlay("myScript.iim");
/* Check for error */
if (ret = 1) {        
      /* do useful stuff */
}else
{
err = "The following error occurred: "+iimGetLastError();
alert(err);
};
```

In the macros script:

```
'this way we pass the variable to the input field
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:ContentPlaceHolder1_txtUsername CONTENT={{i}}
```